# Is this the right way to delete an item from a dict while iteration?

Tags: python

I want to know if this is the normal way to delete conditionally items from a dict. The following code doesn't report an error. Just want to know whether it is safe.

```
dict_items = {'a':1, 'b':2}

for key, value in dict_items.copy().items():
    if some_condition:
       del dict_items[key]
```

Here I use copy() function to avoid operating on the original dict.

EDIT:
Based on suggestions, I did the following:

```
for key in list(dict_items.keys())
        value = dict_items[key]
        if some_condition:
           del dict_items[key]
```

Should this be cheaper and still safe?

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: You don't need to copy the whole thing, but this should be fine.

Comment: Depending on condition, you may want to copy only the keys, e.g., `list(dict_items)`, rather than using `copy`

Comment: @JBallin. But why?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can get a list of keys with just `*dict_items` so doing this `list(dict_items.keys())` is overkill. Actually, double overkill cause `keys()` is already an iterable.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry Using list(dict_items.keys()) is to make a copy on purpose. If just using keys() to delete from the original dict, that would cause problem in iteration.

Comment: @marlon - wrong. '.keys()' just spits out an iterable of key names. It's already a "copy", so to speak. I think you misunderstand how your code works. Python doesn't got to the dict to get the next key on every iteration of the loop. When you call `keys()` python just spits out a list of keys that have no link whatsoever to the dict.

Comment: Changing your question by incorporating suggestions and then asking another is very confusing to others.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry I just tested. If i don't use 'list' to enclose the keys, it will report: 'RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration'. You can try.

Comment: @marion - I actually can't try cause I live in New Orleans and there is no electricity. :D. I wish I could. However my original suggestion was to use `*dict_items` not `keys()`

Answer (score 2):

That's a reasonable way to do it.

An alternative is to create a new dictionary with a dictionary comprehension that inverts the condition.

```
dict_items = {key: value for key, value in dict_items.items() if not some_condition}
```

Comment: That's only an option if the dictionary is not shared, since the original dictionary will remain unmodified.

Comment: In my code, the 'if some_condition' is simplified. In cases where there is more complex logic inside the if conditions, then the dict comprehension won't be that handy.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly a safe way to delete entries from the dict. However copying the entire dict might be expensive, so it might be better to save the to-be-deleted keys in a first loop and then only delete them afterwards:

```py
to_be_deleted = []
for key, value in dict_items.items():
    if some_condition:
        to_be_deleted.append(key)

for key in to_be_deleted:
    del dict_items[key]
```